# How can get 'href' link using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I using selenium-python. and I want to make '**E-mail verify case**'. In the test case, I forwarding '**a href** link.

Yes. It case, just using `find_element_by_partial_link_text` i know. But I do not understand isn't work in my case.

here is case

```
<tbody> 
<tr>
  <td style = "padding-bottom:40px;">
     <a href="(auth link)" target="blank" style="(some style)">Verify address</a>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I am using

1. `find_element_by_partial_link_text("Verify") / ("Verify Address") / ("address")`
2. `find_element_by_css_selector("padding-bottom").get_attribute('href')`

but there are make '`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException`' exception : <

and Try `<br>`
`find_element_by_xpath()`, but that `auth-link` is changing every time.

How to get to **href** link and click this link?

Comment: Share your website link.

Comment: link text(`Verify address`) is fixed or it will be changed like `Verify` or `Verify Address` or `Address`

Comment: Wait. "Verify address" is not the link. The link is whatever is in the `href` attribute. Does Selenium have some kind of _find by content_?

Comment: @bharatk No, i can't because the site is 'Site-in-Company', so link is security data.

Comment: @MrLister I referencing 'https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text'
In this Reference, Link text ("Not link") can be pointing, and it is work other site... Just not this question case. : <

Comment: @LocketGoma Are you sure? Because the example on that page has "continue" both in the href value and in the text content. Also, the description says, _If no element has a ***matching link text attribute***, a `NoSuchElementException` will be raised._, (emphasis mine).

Comment: @MrLister 'find_element_by_partial_link_text()' method is working well 'Non perfect match link text'. enen though 'Not hyperlink' (example : <a href="www.example.com">Test </a> //// find_element_by_partial_link_text("Test") - It is work. // sorry poor comment style.

Answer (score 0):

try to introduce webdriverwait.

I'm changing `link_text` to `partial_link_text`, Just make sure only one `Verify address` link should be present in the UI, otherwise code will not throw any error, It'd just pick the first element.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Verify address')))
```

For clicking just use :

```
element.click()
```

For getting **href**, use :

```
element.get_attribute('href')
```

You can follow this official [Link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) for more.

You need to import these :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Let me know, If you have any more concerns.

Comment: You need to import these : `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC `

Answer (score 0):

You can also try XPATH using text. Try any one from the following list:

```
//a[text()='Verify address']
//a[contains(text(),'Verify address')]
//a[starts-with(text(),'Verify')]
```

After find element you can get_attributes or any other action.

Hope it will solve your problem.